# Wordpress: A page with random posts

Tags: wordpress

I haven't worked much with wordpress, what I am trying to do is have a page that displays random posts.

It would be similar to my main page where the latest posts are shown but it would display random posts every time the page is refreshed.
If the main page is at http://example.com i want my random page to be at http://example.com/random

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable `permalinks` for you wordpress installation by visiting `http://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`, If you would like the title of the post to be the last url segment you would select `Custom Structure` and set this value to `%post_name%`
2. Create a new page template in your current theme folder as described here: [Creating Your Own Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)
3. Create a new page witht the title `Random` and select your newly created page template under `Page Attributes` in the pages edit screen.
4. Then in your page template you would do something like this as [Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503180/filip) suggested:

   ```
   <ul>
   <?php
   $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand');
   $rand_posts = get_posts($args);
   foreach ($rand_posts as $post) : ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
   ```

Comment: Doesn't this pull the same 5 posts over and over? How is it random? The 'orderby' property is just for randomly sorting of the posts after they've been pulled from the DB.

Comment: @MarsAndBack - Nope it will not. If you look on the generated query it should look something like this: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 5`. We first select posts in random order and then limit the result.

Comment: Thx, it makes sense now. During my testing it didn't appear random because of an external issue.

Answer (score 3):

The `orderby` argument to `get_posts` accepts the value `rand`.

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

More info in the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Random_posts

Comment: Thanks, and where do I put this code? do I create a new file in my theme? How do I link to it?

Comment: You should make a new page and make a template for that. Here's a link to the documentation on how to do that. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Templates_by_page-ID_or_page-Slug

Answer (score 1):

Try This ...

1.First a create a custom page template. Name it as random post or a name of your choice!

2.Open the page and remove the default wp loop and Paste the code below

3.To change the no of post change the number ‘1’ to your choice!

> ```
>  <?php
> query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1));
> if (have_posts()) :
> while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
>  
> <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
>  
> <?php the_content(); ?>
>  
> <?php endwhile;
>
> endif; ?>
> ```

source: http://www.yengkokpam.com/displays-random-posts-in-a-page/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to display random posts on your page.

```
<?php
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1));
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: How is this answer any different than the others? I does not really add anything does it?